# How to logically replace a NaN value with previous non-NaN value in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, nan

I have a matrix `data`, that I am saving into `data_Buffer`. All values `<=-999` in `data` are replaced by `NaN` and stored in `data_Buffer`. This is my code:

```
fid = fopen('D:\Data\');
data = fread(fid,'*int16');% 21 x 200 matrix
fclose(fid);

data(data <= -999) = nan;
s = size(data,2);
data_Buffer(:,k:k+s-1) = data;% This is a buffer to store the data matrix
```

Questions/requirements:

1) In `data_Buffer`, how can I see search for `NaN` values in a row and replace them with the previous non-`NaN` value? The algorithm should start from the first column and move towards the last column (i.e., if there is a `NaN` in column 10, it should be replaced by the valid value from column 9).

2) If there are several consecutive `NaN` values, they should be replaced by the previous non-`NaN` value in the row.

Comment: What is `k`? Why not use assume minimal sample data for `data` and explain the expected output?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I just got the solution, I will also update a specific example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it using the [solution provided by Matt at Matlab Central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/50298-replace-nans-with-previous-values) and modified it for case of rows instead of columns:

```
function A = fill_nans(A)
% Replaces the NaN in each column with 
% previous non-NaN values.

for i = 1:size(A,1)
   I = A(1,i);
   for j = 2:size(A,2)
    if isnan(A(i,j))
        A(i,j) = I;
    else
        I  = A(i,j);
    end
end
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer if you solved the problem by yourself. Thanks!

Comment: Good job solving your own problem. Just be aware, that if the first element in a row is `NaN`, it won't get replaced with anything else (but maybe that's that's a problem in your case).